# Viewbag being overwritten when different tabs are opened

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my shopping store ASP.NET MVC application I am using a viewbag to store the url of a particular item (this url can be different for different items/products). So consider I have an item A having url A and item B having url B, if I open both items' pages simultaneously and let's say item B opens first and item A second, then the viewbag value of item A is overwritten by the value of item B.

Why is it so? Why is my viewbag overwritten?

Comment: Different tabs are completely different windows showing different views received from different responses which were generated using their own different viewbags. This isn't an ASP.NET Core quirk, it's how browsers work

Comment: Why do you want or expect the data of one tab to be shared with another? What are you trying to do?

Comment: BTW viewbags don't get overwritten - they temporary to begin with. A ViewBag lives on the server. It's a weakly typed way of passing data to the View before it gets rendered into HTML. Tabs know nothing about the data that generated their HTML. ViewBags aren't persisted from one action call to the next, even when that action is called by the same tab